# cakephp 3 session variable empty in other functions

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Im trying to access session throw different controllers OR in different functions in one controller but when i try access the value from different function , variable is NULL
i read some documents (including [cakephp session cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html)) and more , but i couldnt understand a bit on how to configure the session before using it.

i have a problem in one controller that im trying to use a session but the value is null after im writing it in another function!?

my other question is how can i avoid writing $this->request->session(); in every function that i want to use session.
CODE :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use App\Model\Entity\Answer;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;


class ComlibsController extends AppController {

    public function index() {

    }

    public function getResult(){

    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('comlib'); //change the layout from default
        $live_req = $this->request->data['searchBox']; // get the question

        $session->write('comlib/question' , $live_req);
            $query = $this->Comlibs->LFA($live_req); // get the first answer
            $shown_answerID = array($query[0]['answers'][0]['id'], '2');
    $this->Session->write(['avoidedID'  => $shown_answerID]); //avoid the answer that user saw to repeat agian

              $this->set('question',$query[0]['question']); // does work

        //get the answers result 
        //and send the array to the 
                            $fields = array('id','answer','rate' , 'view' , 'helpful'); 
                            for ($i = 0 ; $i  <= 6 ; $i++) {

                                $this->set('id'.$i,$query[0]['answers'][$i][$fields[0]]);
                                $this->set('answer'.$i,$query[0]['answers'][$i][$fields[1]]);
                                $this->set('rate'.$i,$query[0]['answers'][$i][$fields[2]]);
                                $this->set('view'.$i,$query[0]['answers'][$i][$fields[3]]);
                                $this->set('helpful'.$i,$query[0]['answers'][$i][$fields[4]]);


                            }       

    }
    public function moveon() {

    $this->render('getResult');
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('comlib');
    echo    $question = $session->read('comlib/question'); // empty value echo

    $avoidedIDs = $session->read('avoidedID'); 
    var_dump($avoidedIDs); // returns NULL WHY ?
        $theid = $this->request->here;
        $query = $this->Comlibs->LFM($theid,$avoidedIDs,$question);

            echo 'imcoming';
    }
}
```

Thanks In Adnvanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use these codes for `write` and `read` session data:

`$this->request->session()->write($name, $value);
$this->request->session()->read($name);`

Please read this [section](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#session-data) in CakePHP book.

Comment: both you and Chuug solution ends up with :Error: Call to a member function write() on null
File D:\bookmark\src\Controller\ComlibsController.php
Line: 20

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$this->session()->write('avoidedID', $shown_answerID);
```

instead of

```
$this->session()->write(['avoidedID'  => $shown_answerID]);
```

And try

```
$avoidedIDs = $this->session()->read('avoidedID');
```

instead of

```
$avoidedIDs = $session->read('avoidedID');
```